# Capture the values ​of a cookie before the page finishes loading

Tags: javascript, php

How can I capture the value of a cookie before the page finishes loading ? This is my code in JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

var start_date = document.getElementById('start-date').value;
var end_date = document.getElementById('end-date').value;
var field = document.querySelectorAll('.gform-filter-field')[0].value;
var operator = document.querySelectorAll('.gform-filter-operator')[0].value;
var filter = document.querySelectorAll('.gform-filter-value')[0].value;

console.log(start_date);
console.log(end_date);
console.log(field);
console.log(operator);
console.log(filter);

  
  // Creating a cookie after the document is ready

  
   createCookie("start_date", start_date, "10");
   createCookie("end_date", end_date, "10");
   createCookie("field", field, "10");
   createCookie("operator", operator, "10");
   createCookie("filter", filter, "10");
  
  
  // Function to create the cookie
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
      
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
      
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + 
        escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
  

  alert( start_date );


})
```

These variables I have to capture in my PHP file. This is my code in PHP

```
    add_filter( 'gravityflow_search_criteria_status', 'sh_status_search_criteria', 10, 1 );

function sh_status_search_criteria( $search_criteria ) {
    if (empty($_COOKIE["start_date"])) 
    {
        echo 'The variable is empty, its content is: '.$_COOKIE["start_date"];
    }
    else{
        echo 'The variable is not empty, its content is: '.$_COOKIE["start_date"];
    }

    

    
    
    
    

    /*if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/registro/') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/registro/?entry-id&start-date='.$_COOKIE["start_date"].'&end-date&form-id=1&f[0]&t[0]&v[0]=0&gravityflow-print-timelines=print_timelines&gravityflow-print-page-break=print_page_break'))
      
    
    {$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array ('key' => '7', 'operator' => 'is','value' => get_current_user_id() );}
    return $search_criteria;
    */

}
```

The variables are printed after I reload the page. I would like to know if there is a way to print these variables without having to reload the page again.

Comment: I'm not sure about what do you actually need. But I think that you set the cookies using JavaScript and you need to get it in PHP while the page loads... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.. All me code work fine. The only issue is that it works after loading the screen. I going to share a video. https://www.loom.com/share/549f9ad334f440f9afe4ca7766b5cb5a

Comment: It seems like you are setting the value of date input from get parameter and on load, you are setting the cookie... You need to make it like: You set the cookie in the onChange event of date input. Alternatively, you can set it using PHP's setcookie function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I gave my code another approach and now I do it all with PHP. Very thankful.